# Why doesn't "run-command" return any response in Azure?

Tags: azure, command-line-interface, azure-cli

I'm trying to start a ping in Linux VM in Azure. I would like to use API to do that. I have a blank response with status : 202 accepted.
`https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vmName}/runCommand?api-version=2023-07-01

JSON body :

```
{
  "commandId": "RunShellScript",
  "script": [
    "ping -c 5 8.8.8.8"]
}
```

I can start and stop my VM with HTTP rest with oauth2.

To make sure it's not an API error I used "cloud-shell" to run my ping like this :
`az vm run-command invoke -g MYRG -n VMname --command-id RunShellScript --scripts "ping -c 5 8.8.8.8"`

I get "Running" message for 90 minutes. After I have a timeout.

I opened Outbound port rule : Port 443 Protocol TCP Source Any Destination Any.

Where can be my mistake? It doesn't work with API or CLI.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: 202 - Accepted => means the ARM API accepted your HTTP requests to be processed. It s an asynchronous process so you won't get the command result.

Comment: What are you trying do do by pinging google DNS ?

Comment: Just a test. After I will ping another VM in GCP, I create a demo to show multicloud connectivity to my customers. My API will be started with Nodered and Flexdash palette.

Comment: If I don't get result, what is the way to have it if it's possible? another APIs? In web tutorials the commands in cloud-shell get a result but not me.  I think I have to fix my shell command issue in cloud-shell before.

Comment: I tried the same command as you and ping was successful as [shown](https://i.imgur.com/IH3QUPN.png). @smartstadium

Answer (score 0):

*Need to check below:*

- First, verify that if any firewalls are blocking incoming traffic from the ports you use to connect the virtual machine. This may result in the run command not working as expected.
- In your scenario, the ping command may also fail because it uses the Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP), which cannot enabled by default in Windows Firewall.

  Allow it using portal or [`New-NetFirewallRule`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/new-netfirewallrule?view=windowsserver2022-ps) command.
- Check the [connectivity](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/network-watcher/network-watcher-connectivity-rest.md#check-connectivity-to-a-virtual-machine) of the VM routing with below code. Refer attached MS Doc for relevant information.

```bash
$subscription = "xxx"
$resourceGroup = "Jahnavi"
$vmname = "newvm"
$sourceId = "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourcegroups/Jahnavi/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/newvm"
$destinationId = "5 8.8.8.8"
$desPort = "80"
$requestBody = @"
{
  'source': {
    'resourceId': '${sourceId}',
    'port': xx
  },
  'destination': {
    'address': '${destinationId}',
    'port': ${desPort}
  }
}
"@

$response = armclient post "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vmName}/runCommand?api-version=2023-07-01" $requestBody
```

- Make sure the virtual machine has an outgoing Internet connection to reach the specified IP address. This may include checking NSG rules and ensuring that the virtual machine is properly configured for outbound Internet access.

After checking the above, I tried executing your requirement in my environment with the below CLI command and was able to ping successfully as shown.

```bash
az vm run-command invoke -g Jahnavi -n newvm --command-id RunShellScript --scripts "ping -c 5 8.8.8.8"
```

[image]

You can also check activity logs under virtual machine resource for brief understanding on the error.

[image]

Comment: I checked the firewall and internet connection from my VM as mentioned. No ping dropped. I can ping 8.8.8.8 when I have in SSH remote session on my VM but not with HTTP REST and cloud-shell. In activity log, my command goes to "Accepted" -> "Started" -> "Failed" after 90 minutes.

To ensure it's not just a ping issue, I tried this command: "az vm run-command invoke -g MYRG -n VMname --command-id RunShellScript --scripts "ip a" in cloud-shell but just "202 accepted". No answer